# No such module 'Alamofire' When adding multiple schemes

Tags: ios, xcode7, alamofire

I am trying to create multiple schemes for production/qa/staging ect. I have installed Alamofire using Cocoapods. I have copied the working configuration and changed the name. I have changed the build configuration to match the newly added configuration. When I run the project I get "No such module 'Alamofire'". The original scheme still works fine. What Am I missing?

Comment: Add it to your embedded libraries and linked frameworks

Comment: I saw that on some other posts and tried that with no success.

Answer (score 0):

try run `pod install` this will create some .xcconfig files